# First few characters are cut off from title, RSS reader app android

Tags: java, android, rss

I am currently trying to make an RSS feed reading app in android. Everything works, in the sense that it goes to the RSS feed....and pulls back the data. However, I have noticed that the first item in the list has it's first few characters cut off, and I am not sure why. I am certain it has something to do with my characters() function, but what it is I am not sure of.

If anyone could help me that would be great!

Thanks.

UPDATE

The problem has now been solved for me, thanks to Rakesh Rangani; if you are stuck on a similar problem, check out his answer below...it helped me out!

The code I am referring to:

```
    package com.example.rssapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

/**
 * SAX tag handler
 * 
 * @author ITCuties
 *
 */
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<RssItem> rssItems;

    // Used to reference item while parsing
    private RssItem currentItem;

    // Parsing title indicator
    private boolean parsingTitle;
    // Parsing link indicator
    private boolean parsingLink;

    public RssParseHandler() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
        RssItem g = null;
        //rssItems.add(g);
    }

    public List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return rssItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new RssItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;            
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = false;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null)
                currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));        
        } else if (parsingLink) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code..

```
  package com.example.rssapplication;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
  import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

  import android.util.Log;

  /**
   * SAX tag handler
   * 
   * @author ITCuties
   *
   */
 public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

 private List<RssItem> rssItems;

// Used to reference item while parsing
private RssItem currentItem;

// Parsing title indicator
private boolean parsingTitle;
// Parsing link indicator
private boolean parsingLink;
String strTitle = "";

public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
    //RssItem g = null;
    //rssItems.add(g);
}

public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem();
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;            
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;
        strTitle = "";
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null)
        {
            strTitle = strTitle
                    + (String) new String(ch, start, length).toString();

            currentItem.setTitle(strTitle);       
        }
    } else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Ah yes that has worked thanks! So what exactly was the problem, was it that I was just setting the title without properly converting it to a string?